# Mysql low_priority for innodb: choose which query should be rolled back in a deadlock

Tags: sql, mysql, locking, innodb, deadlock

I have a set of two queries which I've occasionally seen deadlocking.

One is an offline query that only needs to be run occasionally. I'd like some way to have innodb prefer to roll this query back in the event of a deadlock and not the other, sort of like the way the low_priority keyword works for myisam.

Is there any way to tell innodb that it's relatively ok to roll back a given query in the event of a deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:  **no, there is no way.**

As long as foreground processes aren't deadlocking foreground processes, you could try acquiring all locks in advance? (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE).

The other option is to change the background process to acquire locks in the same order as the foreground process.

Answer (score 2):

[There's a work-around](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,65113,65113#msg-65113) solution from the MySQL forums to give a transaction a higher priority by making it update (more) dummy rows.

> InnoDB uses the number of rows a transaction has inserted, updated, or deleted, as the 'size' measure of a transaction, and rolls back the smaller one.